# Proof that largest prime power divisor of n- P(n)->∞ if n->∞

Tags: number-theory

Sorry for my weird post, I'm new here.

n can be expressed as below
[This is what I have done so far:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7wVX.jpg)

Can someone help me prove this 
P(n)->∞ if n->∞

Comment: What is the definition of $P(n)$?

Comment: P(n) is the largest prime power divisor of n

Comment: please clarify the question  a bit as to the exact definition of P(n).